# Formula entering and copying it down to last row

Tags: vba

```
Sheets("Short").Range("Y4") = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($D4&""_""&Y$2,Excess!$A:$Z,3,0),"""")"
Sheets("Short").Range("Y4:Y" & lastrow).Formula = Sheets("Excess").Cells(4, 25).Formula
```

i want to enter the above formula in Y4 cell and copy it down to last row  but it is not working.
code is getting executed but in excel file, it is showing blank

```
Sheets("Short").Range("A4") = "=D4&""_""&COUNTIF($D$4:D4,D4)"
Sheets("Short").Range("A4:A" & lastrow).Formula = Sheets("Excess").Cells(4, 1).Formula
```

this one is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I hav a feeling you just want to recognise this for the sake of knowing - if you truely intend this for layout of an API, I'd propose you would rethink your API - there ought to be no difference inside the behavior, unless both are un-ambiguously exclusive parameters from the person factor of view.

Comment: Dont know much about API, I have an excel data dump, I am trying to create a report based on the raw data where this formula is required